# RewriteRule not capturing backreference

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pcre

I have a RewriteRule in an .htaccess file but am not able to make it work correctly:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!(redirect-build)) redirect-build/index.php?url=$1
```

The backreference $1 isn't captured and Apache rewrites the URL parameter with no value in it. Here is a snippet of the log file:

```
[Fri Mar 13 13:46:26.254929 2020] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10612:tid 1344] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:58838] 127.0.0.1 - - [domain/sid#1c4a1bda5b0][rid#1c4a2df8180/initial] [perdir D:/document-root/path/to/directory/] rewrite 'zalety-jablek' -> 'redirect-build/index.php?url='
[Fri Mar 13 13:46:26.254929 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10612:tid 1344] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:58838] 127.0.0.1 - - [domain/sid#1c4a1bda5b0][rid#1c4a2df8180/initial] split uri=redirect-build/index.php?url= -> uri=redirect-build/index.php, args=url=
```

Is there any solution to it?

Comment: What is it supposed to capture? Can you clarify with examples?

Comment: It's supposed to capture any content inside (redirect-build) provided that it's not equal to "redirect-build" string.

Comment: You can not capture things with a negative lookahead. That is like saying, “okay, everyone whose name is not Joe, get into the car!” - and then expecting that you would know what these people in the car are actually named based on that now. No, of course you don’t know that, all you know is they are _not_ named Joe. Use a RewriteCond to make sure the requested URI does not match what you don’t want, and then capture the actually requested path in the RewriteRule.

Comment: Example:
https://www.example.com/some-path should resolve to: https://www.example.com/redirect-build/index.php?url=some-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example: `example.com/some-path` should resolve to: `example.com/redirect-build/index.php?url=some-path`

In that case you need to adjust your `RewriteRule` pattern to allow it to match & capture value like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ redirect-build/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

- `([\w-]+)` is capture group to match and capture 1+ of any word character or a hyphen
- `RewriteCond` is used to skip existing files and directories from this rewrite

Comment: I've modified the rule a little bit and now it works as it's supposed to:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+) redirect-build/index.php?url=$1`